# How to use username to register and login in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am working on an ASP.NET Core project with identity. In the default `Register.cshtml` page, there is a textbox to enter the email and confirm email.

Similarly in the login page it asks for the email and password to authenticate. However, in my case I want to use a username entered by the user instead of the email. When I searched on the internet, all the samples show replacing email with username, instead of collecting both the email and a username and then use the username and password to log in.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way will be remove that two email input tag on the form and later create a fake email address for that user. For example, when the user type in user1 for the username, the function in HTTP Post can create a email like user1@email.com for the registration.